# Find the number of displayed lines, with folding in Ace

Tags: ace-editor

Within an Ace editor, it is easy to find the number of lines in the edited document with the following:

```js
myEditor.session.getLength();
```

But languages like JSON or XML can be "folded."  That is, children properties or elements can be collapsed so only one single line is displayed for the parent.

Is there a way to get the number of lines actually displayed?  Something like the following:

```js
myEditor.session.getVisibleLength();
```

Note: the ultimate goal is to have an editor that adapts its height on the page to the content it displays (if lines are collapsed, then it should shrink, and if collapsed lines are expanded again, it should increase its height.)

**UPDATE**: After [a user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1743328/a-user)'s response, I use the following.  This is not the answer to the specific question I asked above, but rather the perfect answer to what I was trying to achieve overall:

```js
const myEditor = ace.edit(elem, {minLines: 5, maxLines: 50});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To automatically change the height of the editor use maxLines option, but don't set it to a very large value as performance depends on the number of displayed lines.

Comment: This is *exactly* what I was looking for, thanks!  It's not always easy to find what I am looking for in Ace's doc.